# How to find in Pandas which value counts n times?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a Series like this

```
a = pd.Series([2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 4])
```

I want to know how many times each value repeats in the series, than

```
a.value_counts()
```

provides

```
4    3
2    2
1    1
```

and particularly,

```
a.value_counts().max()
```

gives me the number

```
3
```

which is the number of times 4 is repeted.

My problem is that I don't find any line of code which provides me the number which is repeated 3 times, which is 4. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `idxmax`

```
a.value_counts().idxmax()
```

Or fix your code

```
a[a==a.value_counts().max()].index
```

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
a=a.value_counts()
a
```

output

```
4    3
2    2
1    1
```

then,

```
a.idxmax()
```

this gives 4 as output

this also works:

```
a.index[a.argmax()]
```